# Does Yext provide any value for web only based businesses?

Tags: search-engines, research

I've been researching [Yext](http://www.yext.com/) and trying to understand if it provides value to web-only based business. It seems that if you don't have a physical presence then Yext is not any use. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're in the right track. It appears to me that it is designed to **appear** to help you gain exposure locally.

But all of those links can be claimed by visiting every individual page and registering yourself.

You may be "NOT STANDING OUT" as they say, but how much more you're gonna gain with that is really, really questionable.

I mean, how many visits does your HotFrog page have a month, for example?

If you're only in it for the links, save your money.

I don't know much more about yext, but I don't understand how this service is not frowned upon as it is basically paying for links.

Answer (score 1):

Lets put it in numbers...

For $500 they will give you a HUD to add your info to 58 listing networks. With the ability to "publish Products, Services, Calendars, Staff Bios and Menus around the web."

The maths = $8.62 per site to "fix" the info.

You could probably fix each site in a 1/2 hour max.

Like the previous answer stated, "save your money."